# Changing the direction of content on calendar design

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building my own version of dynamic calendar with `html` `css` and `js`. 
I got two issues:

1. Small issue: The buttons of changing to the next / previous month work as expected just after the second click.
2. Major issue: I can't understand how to fill last month's days on the right ("from the end") direction.

This is my code:

```js
var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
var monthnames = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

var today = new Date();
document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = (today.getMonth()+1);
document.querySelector('#yearChoose').value = today.getFullYear();

// next and previous buttons
document.querySelector('#nextM').addEventListener('click', function() { document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = operator++; buildCalendar()});
document.querySelector('#prevM').addEventListener('click', function() {document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = operator--; buildCalendar()});

// fill days of the week as title
for (var i=0; i < days.length; i++) {
 document.querySelector('#weekdays').innerHTML += '<li><span>'+days[i]+'</span></li>'; 
}
var operator = document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value; // this will later on the function to restrict input value

function buildCalendar() {  
 if (operator > 12) {operator = 1};
 if (operator < 1) {operator = 12}; 
 
 document.querySelector('#days').innerHTML = ' '; // clear records
 
 var month = document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value;
 var year = document.querySelector('#yearChoose').value;
 document.querySelector('#monthName').textContent = monthnames[month-1]; // display month name
 function daysInMonth (month, year) { return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate(); } // constructor to get number of days in chosen month
 var lastMonthDays = daysInMonth(month-1, year);
 var currentMonthDays = daysInMonth(month, year);
 
 var currentFirstDay = new Date(year, month-1 ,1);
 currentFirstDayNum = new Date(currentFirstDay).getDay();
 var currentLastDay = new Date(year, month ,1);
 currentLastDayNum = new Date(currentLastDay).getDay();

 // fill last month's days
 // this cause issue: i need to change the content direction so it will fill from the opposite direction
 for (var i=0; i < currentFirstDayNum; i++) {   
  document.querySelector('#days').innerHTML += '<li style="opacity: 0.5;">'+(lastMonthDays-i)+'</li>';
 }
 // fill the current month days
 for (var i=0; i < currentMonthDays; i++) {
  document.querySelector('#days').innerHTML += '<li>'+(i+1)+'</li>';
 }
 // fill the rest of the board
 var liLength = document.querySelectorAll('#days > li').length;
 var restOfBoard=0;
 while (liLength < 42) {  
  restOfBoard+=1;
  document.querySelector('#days').innerHTML += '<li style="opacity: 0.5;">'+restOfBoard+'</li>';
  liLength++
 } 
}
buildCalendar();
```

```css
ul {list-style-type: none; text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

#month {padding: 30px 0; width: 100%; }
#month li input:first-child { display: none; } /* hide input that control months - will change with js*/
#monthName { display: block; }
#monthName { font-size: 2em; }
#month button {width: auto; padding: 0; font-size: 2em;}
#month #prevM {float: left;}
#month #nextM {float: right;}

#weekdays { padding: 10px 0; background-color: gray; }
#weekdays li {
 display: inline-block;
    color: white;
 width: calc(100% / 7);
}

#days { padding: 10px 0; }
#days li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: calc(100% / 7);
 height: calc(400px / 5); 
}
```

```html
<ul id="month">
 <li><button id="prevM">&#10094;</button> </li>
 <li><button id="nextM">&#10095;</button> </li>
 <li id="monthName"></li>
 <li>
  <input type="number" id="monthChoose" onchange="buildCalendar()" /> 
  <input type="number" id="yearChoose" onchange="buildCalendar()"/>
 </li>
</ul>
<ul id="weekdays"></ul>
<ul id="days"></ul>
```

Note: will glad to hear about things i could do better with this code...

EDIT:
The expected result for the second issue is the lest days of last month. If we take October 2019: the first day is Tuesday so on this week Monday should be the 30th and Sunday the 29th. Can't understand how to fill those days in this order dynamically.

Comment: Are you trying to create a polyfill for `<input type="date">`?

Comment: ...or do you plan on using this UI component to present other calendar information?

Comment: @BDawg since input type date doesn't the same on every browser i want to get full control of the date so i use the type number. I plan to use this as basic UI for calendar system. I know that there are moment.js and fullcalendar.io but i prefer to do that myself.

Comment: What type of calendar, though? A calendar to show date information, or a calendar to simply pick a single date value? (or, perhaps, both?)

Comment: The information would retrieve server side of course. I originally build this system using tables. Now i would like to change this to calendar view. But i stuck with the order of the days. Basically i guess my initial problem is how to do write data using for loop on the opposite direction. I edit the question to explain what i try to achieve.

Comment: I hacked this with hide the non-this-month squares but i really want to make this work this way, and also want to learn how this type of data appending is possible since i don't understand the logic of this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200734/discussion-between-bdawg-and-a-meshu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is quite easy to solve by changing

```
  document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = operator++;
```

to

```
  document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = ++operator;
```

and changing

```
  document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = operator--;
```

to

```
  document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = --operator;
```

Putting `++` after `operator` means you don't increase the value of `operator` until afer you copy its value to the "monthChoose" element, where as putting it beforehand ensures you change its value first. And of course you later use the "monthChoose" element's value to determine the actual month to be displayed.

N.B. It's unclear why you actually need two values here at all - that is just a recipe for confusion. Since `operator` is global, you could just use that all the way through. Alternatively you could use the "monthChoose" element to maintain state if you want to reduce your use of global variables (which generally, you should).

Here's a demo:

```js
var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var monthnames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

var today = new Date();
document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = (today.getMonth() + 1);
document.querySelector('#yearChoose').value = today.getFullYear();

// next and previous buttons
document.querySelector('#nextM').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = ++operator;
  buildCalendar()
});
document.querySelector('#prevM').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value = --operator;
  buildCalendar()
});

// fill days of the week as title
for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  document.querySelector('#weekdays').innerHTML += '<li><span>' + days[i] + '</span></li>';
}
var operator = document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value; // this will later on the function to restrict input value

function buildCalendar() {
  if (operator > 12) {
    operator = 1
  };
  if (operator < 1) {
    operator = 12
  };

  document.querySelector('#days').innerHTML = ' '; // clear records

  var month = document.querySelector('#monthChoose').value;
  var year = document.querySelector('#yearChoose').value;
  document.querySelector('#monthName').textContent = monthnames[month - 1]; // display month name
  function daysInMonth(month, year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  } // constructor to get number of days in chosen month
  var lastMonthDays = daysInMonth(month - 1, year);
  var currentMonthDays = daysInMonth(month, year);

  var currentFirstDay = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
  currentFirstDayNum = new Date(currentFirstDay).getDay();
  var currentLastDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
  currentLastDayNum = new Date(currentLastDay).getDay();

  // fill last month's days
  // this cause issue: i need to change the content direction so it will fill from the opposite direction
  for (var i = 0; i < currentFirstDayNum; i++) {
    document.querySelector('#days').innerHTML += '<li style="opacity: 0.5;">' + (lastMonthDays - i) + '</li>';
  }
  // fill the current month days
  for (var i = 0; i < currentMonthDays; i++) {
    document.querySelector('#days').innerHTML += '<li>' + (i + 1) + '</li>';
  }
  // fill the rest of the board
  var liLength = document.querySelectorAll('#days > li').length;
  var restOfBoard = 0;
  while (liLength < 42) {
    restOfBoard += 1;
    document.querySelector('#days').innerHTML += '<li style="opacity: 0.5;">' + restOfBoard + '</li>';
    liLength++
  }
}
buildCalendar();
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#month {
  padding: 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#month li input:first-child {
  display: none;
}


/* hide input that control months - will change with js*/

#monthName {
  display: block;
}

#monthName {
  font-size: 2em;
}

#month button {
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#month #prevM {
  float: left;
}

#month #nextM {
  float: right;
}

#weekdays {
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

#weekdays li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: calc(100% / 7);
}

#days {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#days li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  height: calc(400px / 5);
}
```

```html
<ul id="month">
  <li><button id="prevM">&#10094;</button> </li>
  <li><button id="nextM">&#10095;</button> </li>
  <li id="monthName"></li>
  <li>
    <input type="number" id="monthChoose" onchange="buildCalendar()" />
    <input type="number" id="yearChoose" onchange="buildCalendar()" />
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="weekdays"></ul>
<ul id="days"></ul>
```

I'm afraid I don't understand precisely what you mean by your second problem. Perhaps you can give a clearer description / diagram showing what you want to happen and then I can update this answer?

Comment: Thank you for solving my first issue. I update the question and can't wait to see your updated answer (:

Comment: As for using two variables that points to the same data, i created the operator mainly to control the input value, i find it easier to debug my code that way - even though i completely agree that it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

So i finally managed to solve the second problem: Gave the lastMonthDays a unique class, sort it by it content, append the sorting elements, and then proceed with the rest of code.

For this i modified [this script](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Javascript/Javascript_DOM_How_to/Element/Sort_DOM_elements_with_sort_.htm) for my needs.

Thanks everybody.